# Peach Tree, bark darkening and peeling/cracking

Tags: trees, diagnosis, fruit-trees, tree-care

I have two peach trees in close proximity to each other. One is healthy and shows no signs on distress, however the other one...

- Leaves did not fully come in.
- Has areas of darkened bark that ooze small amounts of sap.
- Recently developed cracking/splitting/holes in the bark.

I tried to cut the branches off that did not grow leaves as an attempt to stymie any disease it may have. However, it does not seem to be getting any better. I have not physcially seen and insects or other pests around the tree.

**What could be ailing my peach tree?** It's peaches are really yummy and I want to eat them again this summer!!!

Location: Pittsburgh, PA, USA

[image: dark bark]

[image: splitting bark]

[image: full tree]

Comment: Don't know what it was, but I ended up cutting the trees down :(